# Multivariable calculus problem with improper integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This is a detailed question from *Introduction to Calculus and Analysis*, by Courant & John.

> **1.8b(a) Exercise 2**
>
> Let 
>   $$F(y) = \int_0^1 \frac{(x-1)x^y}{\log x} dx \quad \text{for} \; y>1$$
>   Consider $\epsilon \in (0,1/100).$
>
> (a) Prove that there exists two constants $c_1, c_2$ such that
>   $$\left|\int_{1-\epsilon}^1 \frac{(x-1)x^y}{\log x} dx - \frac{1}{y+1}\right| \le \frac{1}{y+1}e^{-c_1(y+1)\epsilon} + c_2\epsilon^2 .$$
>   for any $\epsilon \in (0,1/100)$ and $y > 1$.
>
> > (Hint given by professor: $\log(1-t) = -t + O(t^2)$ for *t* small, and >$\frac{x-1}{\log x} = 1 + O(\vert x-1 \vert)$ for $\vert x-1 \vert$ small.)
>
> (b) Prove that there exists a constant $c_3$ such that
>   $$\left|\int_0^{1-\epsilon}  \frac{(x-1)x^y}{\log x} dx\right| \le e^{-c_3y\epsilon} .$$
>   for any $\epsilon \in (0,1/100)$ and $y > 1$.
>
> > (Hint given by professor: The value of $\frac{(x-1)x}{\log x}$ is between $0$ and $1$ for $x \in [0,1]$)

---

Some attempts to solve this problem:

$$\int_0^1 x^y\,dx = \frac{1}{y+1}$$
$$\int_{1-\epsilon}^1 x^y\,dx < \frac{1}{y+1}$$ for $\epsilon > 0.$
So, 
$$\left|\int_{1-\epsilon}^1 \frac{(x-1)x^y}{\log (x)}\,dx - \frac{1}{y+1}\right| > \left|\int_{1-\epsilon}^1 \left(\frac{(x-1)x^y}{\log (x)} - x^y\right)\,dx \right|$$

By applying the hint,

$$ \left|\int_{1-\epsilon}^1 x^y\left(\frac{x-1}{\log (x)}-1\right)\,dx\right| = \left|\int_{1-\epsilon}^1 x^y(1-x)\,dx\right|$$
$$= \frac{1}{y+1}(1-(1-\epsilon)^{y+1}) - \frac{1}{y+2}(1-(1-\epsilon)^{y+2}).$$

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange, it is appreciated, especially when posting homework or class questions (as you have sort of admitted this is by adding hints from professors) to show what work you have already done towards solving the question

Comment: Attempts have added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the "hint" that $\log(1-t)=-t+O(t^2)$ for $t\to 0$, we see that

$$\begin{align}
\int_{1-\epsilon}^1\frac{(x-1)}{\log(x)}x^y\,dx&=\int_{\epsilon}^0\frac{t}{\log(1-t)}(1-t)^y\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^\epsilon \left(1+O(t)\right)(1-t)^y\,dt\\\\
&=\frac{1-(1-\epsilon)^{y+1}}{y+1}+\int_0^\epsilon O(t)(1-t)^y\,dt\\\\
&=\frac{1}{y+1}-\frac{e^{(y+1)\log(1-\epsilon)}}{y+1}+\int_0^\epsilon O(t)e^{y\log(1-t)}\,dt
\end{align}$$

Next, we use the mean value theorem to assert that there exists a number $\xi\in (0,\epsilon)$ such that $\log(1-\epsilon)=-\frac{1}{1-\xi}\epsilon=-c_1\epsilon$.

Furthermore, we have $e^{y\log(1-t)}=e^{-yt+O(t^2)}=1-yt+O(t^2)$ so that $\int_0^\epsilon O(t)\,dt=O(\epsilon^2)=-c_2\epsilon^2$ for some $c_2$.

Putting it all together reveals

$$\left|\int_{1-\epsilon}^1\frac{(x-1)}{\log(x)}x^y\,dx-\frac{1}{y+1}\right|=\frac{e^{-c_1(y+1)\epsilon}}{y+1}+c_2\epsilon^2$$

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.  -Mark

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand the part when you integrate $\int_0^\epsilon (1-yt+O(t^2))\,dt$.

Comment: Well, you're missing an extra $O(t)$ term.   We are integrating $$\int_0^\epsilon O(t)e^{y\log(1-t)}\,dt=\int_0^\epsilon O(t)\left(1-yt+O(t^2) \right)\,dt=O(\epsilon^2)=-c_2\epsilon^2$$for some $c_2$

Comment: But how do we integrate this? By parts or something?

Comment: @Tsai Note that if $f(x)=O(g(x))$ as $x\to x_0$, then there exists a number $C$ such that $f(x)\le Cg(x)$.  Then, $\int f(x)\,dx=C\int g(x)\,dx$.  Can you integrate $x$, $x^2$, and  $x^3$?  For example, $\int O(t)\,dt=O(t^2)$.

Comment: So, by integration, I get $O(\epsilon^2)+O(\epsilon^3)+O(\epsilon^4). $ But why can we omit $ \epsilon^3 & \epsilon^4 $?

Comment: Good question.  The higher order terms are much smaller.  That is, as $\epsilon\to 0$, $O(\epsilon^3)/\epsilon^2=C\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: @Tsai Since you're new to the site, I wanted to let you know that when you have enough reputation points, you can also up vote answers.